# Android (Eclipe) Video View File name path?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, video

I'm here with what I think to be an easy doubt, but it's blowing my mind >.<

I'm pretty newbie to Java, and I wanted to make an app for android, but I'm stuck with the video player's coding.

I'm using this code, which I found on the internet (I think it was in stackoverflow, but not sure)

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.reveal;
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
vv.start();
```

what the heck I put on the filename, where it has "android.resource://"

I want to play a video when I open a certain activity. My video is located in the drawable-ldpi's folder.
The video's file name is reveal.wmv

Can you guys help me solving it?

Best regards :D 
*Sorry about my english :/*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking about it a little wrong.  I know that in most tutorials they use "filename" as somewhere that you should insert the name, but in this case it is not so.  The line

```
String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.reveal;
```

is setting the file path and filename of the video.  In this case, it is setting a path to the raw folder and to the video "reveal"  If you have not already, you should create the raw folder and place it in the res folder.  That is where you will store all video and sound media.

In the next line:

```
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
```

the "filename" is substituting for the enter path, so leave that as it is.  In the previous line you named the String that is pointing to the video, "filename"  It could also have been programmed as so:

```
String elmo = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.reveal;
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(elmo));
```

I have seen that it is best to use mp4 format files.  I know that is just the extension and I am not sure about the actual codec, but that should lead you in a direction.  Notice that the extension is not used in the file name itself.  Android will simply search for the name and load the file regardless.  If it is the wrong format or acceptable extension, it simply will not play.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for being late, it really helps a lot :D
I already selected this answer, but if I need help, can I count with your help? :D

Answer (score 0):

The drawables folder is not for videos. Put it in res/raw/ (you may need to create). You will need to change the resource name (R.raw.yourfilename), but other than that, your example looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to declare the `PATH` is wrong ... first you have to put your video file in /asset folder and then use `getAssests()` method .. it 'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Just move reveal.wmv from drawable-ldpi folder to raw folder, then it will work well. If you don't have raw folder, create it under res folder.